# nginx change referer for proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have set up a very basic proxy rule in nginx.
However the resources where the request are proxyed do a referer check. It must be the same domain the service is running at.
I therefore need to change the referer. I tried a proxy_set_header but that doesn´t seem to work.

Am I missing something or is there any other way to do this?

```
location /api/v1/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.10.10:8080;
    proxy_set_header Referer "http://192.168.10.10";
}
```

Comment: Were you able to find a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

You say that the proxied server asks for a domain name as a referer. Try that domain name instead of IP address.

```
proxy_set_header Referer "http://proxied-domain-here.com";
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having a similar issue, which was solved by quoting the new referer string and adding "http://" to the beginning.

Comment: This can be a bad idea for CSRF. However, nginx doesn't seem to provide a way to edit the referer header.

Answer (score 2):

Few years later, but this could be helpful to somewhere, you miss the **port** at the referer header (**:8080**):

```
    proxy_set_header Referer "http://192.168.10.10:8080";
```

I hope can be helpful.